# Populating a Class with separate SQL Procedures

Tags: c#, sql, .net, api, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make my .NET API smarter. When I get data from my API, I have to make API calls for each of the results. Currently, I have four end points:

```
    [HttpGet("/api/GetCustomer/{customerNumber}")] 
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetCustomer(string customerNumber)
    {
        var custNum = new SqlParameter("@custNum", customerNumber);
        return await context.Customer.FromSql("EXEC sp_GetCustomer @custNum", custNum).ToArrayAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet("/api/GetCustomerTransactions/{customerNumber}/{startDate}/{endDate}")] 
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerTransaction>> GetCustomerTransactions(string customerNumber, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var custNum = new SqlParameter("@custNum", customerNumber);
        var dateFrom = new SqlParameter("@dateFrom", startDate);
        var dateTo = new SqlParameter("@dateTo", endDate);
        return await context.CustomerTransactions.FromSql("EXEC sp_GetCustomerTransactions @custNum, @dateFrom, @dateTo", custNum, dateFrom, dateTo)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToArrayAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet("/api/GetCustomerTransactionDetails/{customerNumber}/{storeNumber}/{transactionNumber}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerTransactionDetail>> GetCustomerTransactionDetails(string customerNumber, string storeNumber, string transactionNumber)
    {
        var custNum = new SqlParameter("@custNum", customerNumber);
        var storeNum = new SqlParameter("@storeNum", storeNumber);
        var transNum = new SqlParameter("@transNum", transactionNumber);
        return await context.TransactionDetails.FromSql("EXEC sp_GetCustomerTransactionDetails @custNum, @storeNum, @transNum", custNum, storeNum, transNum)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToArrayAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet("/api/GetProduct/{productSku}/")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetProduct(string productSku)
    {
        var sku = new SqlParameter("@sku", productSku);
        return await context.Product.FromSql("EXEC sp_GetProduct @sku", sku)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToArrayAsync();
    }
```

I have a one to many relationship down the line. CustomerTransactions > CustomerTransactionDetails > Products. I'm thinking the solution is to add a collection to each of the classes, but I'm not sure how to populate that yet since the results are in another SQL Procedure.

```
public class CustomerTransaction
{
    [Key] public string KwiNumber { get; set; }
    public int StoreNumber { get; set; }
    public int TransactionNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TransactionTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CustomerTransactionDetail> CustomerTransactionDetails { get; set; }

    public CustomerTransaction()
    {
        CustomerTransactionDetails = new Collection<CustomerTransactionDetail>();
    }
}
```

Comment: One reason why stored procedures are not flexible. You can always combine results of all procedures in one object(collection of objects). Or drop stored procedures and retrieve required data with Linq to Entities

Comment: That's a shame... Maybe I'll try doing something more on the SQL side. I wanted to use procedures for performance reasons.

Comment: Do you really have noticeable performance difference between stored procedures and Linq to Entities queries?

Comment: It's pretty noticeable in my case. The improvement is 2 to 7 seconds.